# setw(n) and alignment not working the way I need it to - C++

Tags: c++, setw

Here is my code for context. This is my second homework assignment intro to programming course and I have used everything we've learned in this assignment. I am not allowed to use anything I have not learned.

The part I am concerned with is the output at the very bottom (commented as information output). Currently, I am struggling to get everything perfectly right aligned (the last letter or number in the right hand column must align with each other as if I were typing them from the right.

Everything except the patient's name, room type, and days spent in the hospital are aligning properly, decimals aligned and everything. Changing the setw(10) to anything larger does nothing beneficial (ex: i had all of them to setw(40) and it still did not align anything properly. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//constants
const float PRIVATE = 125.00;
const float SEMI = 95.00;
const float WARD = 75.00;
const float TV = 3.50;
const float PHONE = 1.75;

int main()
{   //local variables
    string fname, lname, roomType, tvAccess, phoneAccess;
    int id, days;
    float roomBill, roomPrice, tvCharge, phoneCharge;
    bool error = false;

    //data collection/output
    cout << "Welcome to the hospital self-service program. Your bill will be calculated here.\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your first and last name: ";
    cin >> fname;
    cin >> lname;
    cout << fname << " " << lname << ", please enter the four digit identification number found on your hospital wristband: ";
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Please enter the number of days spent in the hospital: ";
    cin >> days;
    cout << "\nEnter the type of room you stayed in: \nEnter P for room type: Private \nEnter S for room type: Semi-Private\nEnter W for room type: Ward \n" << endl;
    cin >> roomType;
    cout << "\nDid your room come with access to Television? Y/N: ";
    cin >> tvAccess;
    cout << "Did your room come with access to a Telephone? Y/N: ";
    cin >> phoneAccess;

    //if and elses
    if (roomType == "P" || roomType == "p")
    {
        error = false;
        roomType = "Private Room";
        roomPrice = PRIVATE;
    }
    else if (roomType == "S" || roomType == "s")
    {
        error = false;
        roomType = "Semi-Private Room";
        roomPrice = SEMI;

    }
    else if (roomType == "W" || roomType == "w")
    {
        error = false;
        roomType = "Ward Room";
        roomPrice = WARD;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Room type not valid. Exit the program and try again." << endl;
        error = true;
    }
    if (tvAccess == "Y" || tvAccess == "y")
        tvCharge = TV;
    else
        tvCharge = 0;

    if (phoneAccess == "Y" || phoneAccess == "y")
        phoneCharge = PHONE;
    else
        phoneCharge = 0;


    //information output
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "\n\nPatient Full Name: " << setw(10) << right << fname << " " << lname << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Identification Number: " << setw(10) << right << id << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Days spent in hospital: " << setw(10) << right << days << " day(s)" <<  endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Room Type: " << setw(10) << right << roomType << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Room Charge: " << setw(10) << right << roomPrice * days << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Television Charge: " << setw(10) << right << tvCharge * days << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Telephone Charge: " << setw(10) << right << phoneCharge * days << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << left << "Total Charge: " << setw(10) << right << days * (phoneCharge + tvCharge + roomPrice) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is an image] for clarification.

Comment: Please give us your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, I thought my explanation was adequate. Let me see if I can create a picture of it.

Comment: you can capture output like this:   ./aout arg1 >> result.txt

Comment: for starters you should lose the \n\n in front `cout << setw(24) << left << "\n\n` and write it before setw. `cout << std::endl << std::endl << setw(24) << ...`

Comment: ANDERS K!!! You are the man, that was the problem!!! I love you dude.

Comment: @LeetalCohen if it solved feel free to accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason, they are not formatted correctly, is, that the `setw` in

```
setw(10) << right << fname << " " << lname << endl;
```

and

```
setw(10) << right << days << " day(s)" <<  endl;
```

only applies to the first variable, i.e. `fname` and `days`. Everything else is just appended. You need to concatenate these strings first before using `setw` here.

Comment: so i think this is what you mean, I added this towards the end of my code. string name = fname + ' ' + lname;
Now i have both the first, last name, and a space all stored in one string.  it stills isn't working as intended though. Everything is right aligned now except for the name, which is now a few spaces to the left.